# Interactive video using Media Source Extension API

Tags: javascript, architecture, video-streaming

## Background

I am trying to create an interactive video player using the HTML5 video element.

I came across Media Source Extensions API, and got it working.

```
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mime);
```

Next I make a REST call to fetch the video segment and attach it to the source buffer.
`sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);`

## Problem

- I am trying to fire events when the newly loaded video segment reaches a certain time.
- Also, I want to be able to seamlessly loop a video segment, which exits and continues to another video segment on interaction.

How can I achieve these features?

Comment: Hi. I know it's late, but did you find a solution to those problems?